# Django and multiple databases

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multiple-databases

My current Django setup uses [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) as the main database to store models. Now for my project I need to connect to a remote [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database and retrieve data from it. Is it possible to do this by using built-in Django and [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) features or I will need to use library such as [Psycopg2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/2.0.4)?

It would be great for me, if I will be able to use the Object-relational mapper of Django for this remote database.

Any ideas would be more than welcome.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268089/multiple-database-support-in-django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django Project is working on [Multiple Database Support](http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2009/11/state-of-multidb-in-django.html). There is also a recent (Nov 10 2009) blog post about ["The state of MultiDB (in Django)"](http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2009/11/state-of-multidb-in-django.html).

Update: [Multiple Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/) is supported since [Django v1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.2/) (release May 2010).