# Django models interface with dynamic connection

Tags: python, django

I have databases with identical schemas spread over several servers and I need to route a Django model to read from the databases on different servers. I know I can use routers to send reads to different databases in `settings.DATABASES`, but the addresses could change at any time and keeping `DATABASES` up-to-date would be impractical.

Django appears to route models based mostly database aliases, which it uses to look up the proper connection in `django.db.connections`. Is there a good way to dynamically add connections and aliases to the `ConnectionHandler` instance without having to hack the `_connections` attribute? Should I find some way to dynamically populate `settings.DATABASES`?

Comment: Although is an old question, Dave Aaron Smith's answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268089/multiple-database-support-in-django
Or the doc's answer: `./manage.py syncdb --database=users`, where `users` is the unfortunate alias!
Can't give a clear answer(which I too need it), I've google it, but nothing yet!

Comment: The solution I figured out was to dynamically add dicts to the DATABASES dict in settings. Basically, whenever I needed a new server, I would clone a suitable config already in DATABASES, replace the host with the appropriate server name or IP, then add it to DATABASES with an alias of the server name.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I find some way to dynamically populate `settings.DATABASES`?

If you mean to alter *settings.py* at runtime, [you should not](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime).

Comment: In hindsight this may have been better off as a comment to your question.